# What really is 'glmnet' when used in caret in R for binary classification?

Tags: r, regression, caret, elastic-net

> like lasso and ridge, elastic net can also be used for classification
> by using the deviance instead of the residual sum of squares. This
> essentially happens automatically in caret if the response variable is
> a factor.

This is from topepo caret github. However, although I searched the internet. No one one really seems to tell what 'glmnet' really is ?
For example, if I do the following, for a binary classication task.

glm_net = train( y ~ . , data = train_set, method = 'glmnet', trControl = fitControl, metric = 'ROC')

What is it really? A logistic regression? And it also come with lasso and ridge regression regularization, but it cant be linear regression because it is classification..

Comment: GLMNet = GLM + Elastic-Net penalization

Answer (score 2):

It's logistic regression with different penalization/regularization (LASSO=L1 regularization, or ridge=L2 regularization, or elastic net = LASSO & ridge = L1 and L2 regularization). It is a regression model, but the predicted probabilities can then be used for categorization (if that makes sense). I assume the name `glmnet` comes from Generalized Linear Model (generalized = using link functions & other distributions to generalize regression to binary and other outcomes such as Poisson etc.) and elastic-net.

By the way, the package also has some other options like averaging a penalized with a non-penalized for the non-zero coefficients, but that's still logistic regression.